# Resizing or Clipping after a rotation

Tags: android

I have a 10x10 tablelayout with each cell containing an ImageView. I simulate the moving across this gamegrid by updating the pictures in each grid on a move event. I also rotate the image to align the image with the direction of travel. My problem is that as the image rotates it causes my cell rows and columns to expand to fit the rotated image.

What I would like is to have the image cropped to remain within the dimensions of the table row and columns. If that isnt possible then I would like to scale the image to remain within the dimensions of the original table cell.

Another potential issue is that the images are getting scaled initially to fit into the cells (this is done automatically as the table expands to fill the screen). I don't want to change that behavior. I just want to trim off the corners of the image as they pass the original boundaries of the table cell when they are rotated.

My rotation code is below:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate((float) (360 - sector.getShip().getHeading()));
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(image.getContext().getResources(), getShip().getGridSymbol());
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true));
image.setImageResource(sector.getShip().gridParams.default);
```

My table configuration is below:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/quadrantGrid" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#000000">
...
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="1" android:background="#404040" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid00"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid01"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid02"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid03"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid04"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid05"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid06"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid07"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid08"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid09"></ImageView>
</TableRow>
...
```

**UPDATE:**
I found a solution, though I'm not sure its the most efficient solution.

All my images are 25x25. And so the OS figures how to scale those images to fit into the cell. The solution just performs two operations. First it rotates, and then it creates a smaller image from the rotated image. (note: When I created my image I made sure the important parts of the image would be contained within a circle with a diameter of the width of the image to allow for this type of cropping).

My code is below. I would prefer to perform both operations within one method, but Im not sure how so I just break it down into two steps.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate((float) (360 - sector.getShip().getHeading()));
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(image.getContext().getResources(), getShip().getGridSymbol());
bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, 25, 25, matrix, true);
int x = (bMap.getWidth() - 25) / 2;
int y = (bMap.getHeight() - 25) / 2;
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, x, y, 25, 25));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution has to leverage the "getMeasuredHeight()" of the image. I didnt have to use the getMeasuredWidth() because for my particular layout the height is the limiting factor.

Here is the final bitmap code that works:

```
private Bitmap getRotatedShipBitmap(SectorGridImageView image,
        Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    int yHeight = (image.getMeasuredHeight() == 0) ? bitmap.getHeight()
            : image.getMeasuredHeight();
    int xWidth = yHeight;
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - xWidth) / 2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() - yHeight) / 2;
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x, y, xWidth, yHeight);
}
```

Comment: Couple of cautions on this:
1) All the images in the table need to be the same size or you will have to add more logic to work with varying sizes.
2) If you have some scaling at work, you will probably have to write more logic to ensure the image isn't bigger than the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to each ImageView item in your xml layout.

Comment: I had previously tried that, though it doesnt work because my images need scaled initially to fit in the cells. The table is dynamically sized at startup to fill the screen and then the images it displays are scaled to fit within the cells. Once that initialization is done. I need to prevent the cells from growing as the image is rotated.

I want the system to initially determine all the sizes and initial scaling and then not to change after that has been set.